# single lane tunnel mutex example in c windows

Tags: c, windows, mutex, semaphore, critical-section

I'm trying to solve the classic "single lane tunnel" semaphore/mutex problem. 
This is the code I wrote but it doesn't work and I can't understand why.
In theory the cars coming from opposite direction should cross ONLY if the tunnel is already in use by cars going in the same direction otherwise they should wait, the output should be something like:

```
car1_leftToRight crossing
car2_leftToRight crossing
car1_leftToRight end crossing
car2_leftToRight end crossing  (ALL cars leftToRight have crossed)
car1_rightToLeft start crossing 
etc..
```

but my current output is the one that you can see in the image I attached.
I also created a global variable (globalCarsCrossing) to keep track on how many cars are currently crossing the bridge and as you can see it seems that cars from opposite directions are crossing at the same time!
[image]

Do you have some suggestion on what I'm doing wrong?

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <WinBase.h>
#include <process.h> //include for function _beginthreadex

int globalCarsCrossing = 0;

typedef struct {
    int numTraversingCar;
    int crossingTime;
    int arrivalTime; //0 - arrivalTime -> random number, how much time pass between cars arrival
    HANDLE mutex;
    LPHANDLE bridgeMutexPtr;
    int direction;
} ThParams;

DWORD WINAPI thFunction(LPVOID thParamsPtr);
void crossBridge();

int _tmain(int argc, LPTSTR argv[])
{
    int timeL2R, timeR2L, timeARRIVAL, nL2R, nR2L;
    LPHANDLE thL2Rarray, thR2Larray;
    ThParams paramsL2R, paramsR2L;
    HANDLE bridgeMutex;

    if (argc < 6) 
    {
        _ftprintf(stderr, _T("missing parameters: <timeL2R> <timeR2L> <timeARRIVAL> <nL2R> <nR2L>\n"));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    timeL2R = _ttoi(argv[1]); //WINDOWS version of "atoi"
    timeR2L = _ttoi(argv[2]);
    timeARRIVAL = _ttoi(argv[3]);
    nL2R = _ttoi(argv[4]);
    nR2L = _ttoi(argv[5]);

    //allocates all threads array
    thL2Rarray = (LPHANDLE)malloc(nL2R * sizeof(HANDLE));
    thR2Larray = (LPHANDLE)malloc(nR2L * sizeof(HANDLE));

    //initialize all parameters
    bridgeMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);

    //create structs for threads
    paramsL2R.mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    paramsL2R.bridgeMutexPtr = &bridgeMutex;
    paramsL2R.arrivalTime = timeARRIVAL;
    paramsL2R.numTraversingCar = 0;
    paramsL2R.crossingTime = timeL2R;
    paramsL2R.direction = 0;

    //paramsR2L.criticalSectionPtr = &criticalSectionR2L;
    paramsR2L.mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    paramsR2L.bridgeMutexPtr = &bridgeMutex;
    paramsR2L.arrivalTime = timeARRIVAL;
    paramsR2L.numTraversingCar = 0;
    paramsR2L.crossingTime = timeR2L;
    paramsR2L.direction = 1;

    //create L2R threads 
    for (int i = 0; i<nL2R; i++)
        thL2Rarray[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, thFunction, &paramsL2R, 0, NULL);
    //create R2L threads 
    for (int i = 0; i<nR2L; i++)
        thR2Larray[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, thFunction, &paramsR2L, 0, NULL);

    //wait for ALL threads to return
    WaitForMultipleObjects(nL2R, thL2Rarray, TRUE, INFINITE);
    WaitForMultipleObjects(nR2L, thR2Larray, TRUE, INFINITE);
    _tprintf(_T("all threads are returned\n"));

    //closa all thread handle
    for (int i = 0; i<nL2R; i++)
        CloseHandle(thL2Rarray[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i<nR2L; i++)
        CloseHandle(thR2Larray[i]);

    ////free and release everything
    free(thL2Rarray);
    free(thR2Larray);
    CloseHandle(bridgeMutex);
    CloseHandle(paramsR2L.mutex);
    CloseHandle(paramsL2R.mutex);

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI thFunction(LPVOID thParamsPtr)
{
    ThParams *paramsPtr = (ThParams *)thParamsPtr;

    WaitForSingleObject(paramsPtr->mutex, INFINITE);
        paramsPtr->numTraversingCar = paramsPtr->numTraversingCar + 1;

        if (paramsPtr->numTraversingCar == 1)
            WaitForSingleObject(*(paramsPtr->bridgeMutexPtr), INFINITE);

        globalCarsCrossing++;
        _tprintf(_T("%d crossing direction: %d, TOT_cars_from_this_direction: %d,  GLOBAL_CARS_CROSSING: %d\n"), GetCurrentThreadId(), paramsPtr->direction, paramsPtr->numTraversingCar, globalCarsCrossing);
    ReleaseMutex(paramsPtr->mutex);

    crossBridge();

    WaitForSingleObject(paramsPtr->mutex, INFINITE);
        paramsPtr->numTraversingCar = paramsPtr->numTraversingCar - 1;
        globalCarsCrossing--;
        _tprintf(_T("%d end crossing direction: %d, TOT_cars_from_this_direction: %d,  GLOBAL_CARS_CROSSING %d\n"), GetCurrentThreadId(), paramsPtr->direction, paramsPtr->numTraversingCar, globalCarsCrossing);
        if (paramsPtr->numTraversingCar == 0) {
            _tprintf(_T("RELEASED\n"));
            ReleaseMutex(*(paramsPtr->bridgeMutexPtr));
        }
    ReleaseMutex(paramsPtr->mutex);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from your `WaitForSingleObject` call:

> Return code: `WAIT_ABANDONED 0x00000080L`
>
> The specified object is a mutex object that was not released by the thread that owned the mutex object before the owning thread terminated. Ownership of the mutex object is granted to the calling thread and the mutex state is set to nonsignaled.
>
> If the mutex was protecting persistent state information, you should check it for consistency.

Thread 2944 got the mutex on tunnel, made its car cross and finish, without releasing the mutex.

When thread 3560 calls `WaitForSingleObject`, this function returns `WAIT_ABANDONED`

Your code cannot do what you want because **a mutex took by a thread must be released by the same thread**.

A semaphore is more appropriated to lock the tunnel.

---

Edit:

I first post I suggested using `CriticalSection`, but like `Mutex`, a `CriticalSection` must be acquired and release by the same thread.

---

Example implementation:

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <WinBase.h>
#include <process.h> //include for function _beginthreadex

int globalCarsCrossing = 0;

typedef struct {
    int numTraversingCar;
    int crossingTime;
    int arrivalTime; //0 - arrivalTime -> random number, how much time pass between cars arrival
    HANDLE mutex;
    HANDLE bridgeSem;
    int direction;
} ThParams;

DWORD WINAPI thFunction(LPVOID thParamsPtr);
void crossBridge();

int _tmain(int argc, LPTSTR argv[])
{
    int timeL2R, timeR2L, timeARRIVAL, nL2R, nR2L;
    LPHANDLE thL2Rarray, thR2Larray;
    ThParams paramsL2R, paramsR2L;
    HANDLE bridgeSem;

    if (argc < 6) 
    {
        _ftprintf(stderr, _T("missing parameters: <timeL2R> <timeR2L> <timeARRIVAL> <nL2R> <nR2L>\n"));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    timeL2R = _ttoi(argv[1]); //WINDOWS version of "atoi"
    timeR2L = _ttoi(argv[2]);
    timeARRIVAL = _ttoi(argv[3]);
    nL2R = _ttoi(argv[4]);
    nR2L = _ttoi(argv[5]);

    //allocates all threads array
    thL2Rarray = (LPHANDLE)malloc(nL2R * sizeof(HANDLE));
    thR2Larray = (LPHANDLE)malloc(nR2L * sizeof(HANDLE));

    //initialize all parameters
    bridgeSem = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 1, 1, NULL);

    //create structs for threads
    paramsL2R.mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    paramsL2R.bridgeSem = bridgeSem;
    paramsL2R.arrivalTime = timeARRIVAL;
    paramsL2R.numTraversingCar = 0;
    paramsL2R.crossingTime = timeL2R;
    paramsL2R.direction = 0;

    //paramsR2L.criticalSectionPtr = &criticalSectionR2L;
    paramsR2L.mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    paramsR2L.bridgeSem = bridgeSem;
    paramsR2L.arrivalTime = timeARRIVAL;
    paramsR2L.numTraversingCar = 0;
    paramsR2L.crossingTime = timeR2L;
    paramsR2L.direction = 1;

    //create L2R threads 
    for (int i = 0; i<nL2R; i++)
        thL2Rarray[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, thFunction, &paramsL2R, 0, NULL);
    //create R2L threads 
    for (int i = 0; i<nR2L; i++)
        thR2Larray[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, thFunction, &paramsR2L, 0, NULL);

    //wait for ALL threads to return
    WaitForMultipleObjects(nL2R, thL2Rarray, TRUE, INFINITE);
    WaitForMultipleObjects(nR2L, thR2Larray, TRUE, INFINITE);
    _tprintf(_T("all threads are returned\n"));

    //closa all thread handle
    for (int i = 0; i<nL2R; i++)
        CloseHandle(thL2Rarray[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i<nR2L; i++)
        CloseHandle(thR2Larray[i]);

    ////free and release everything
    free(thL2Rarray);
    free(thR2Larray);
    CloseHandle(bridgeSem);
    CloseHandle(paramsR2L.mutex);
    CloseHandle(paramsL2R.mutex);

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI thFunction(LPVOID thParamsPtr)
{
    ThParams *paramsPtr = (ThParams *)thParamsPtr;

    WaitForSingleObject(paramsPtr->mutex, INFINITE);
        paramsPtr->numTraversingCar = paramsPtr->numTraversingCar + 1;

        if (paramsPtr->numTraversingCar == 1)
            WaitForSingleObject(paramsPtr->bridgeSem, INFINITE);

        globalCarsCrossing++;
        _tprintf(_T("%d crossing direction: %d, TOT_cars_from_this_direction: %d,  GLOBAL_CARS_CROSSING: %d\n"), GetCurrentThreadId(), paramsPtr->direction, paramsPtr->numTraversingCar, globalCarsCrossing);
    ReleaseMutex(paramsPtr->mutex);

    crossBridge();

    WaitForSingleObject(paramsPtr->mutex, INFINITE);
        paramsPtr->numTraversingCar = paramsPtr->numTraversingCar - 1;
        globalCarsCrossing--;
        _tprintf(_T("%d end crossing direction: %d, TOT_cars_from_this_direction: %d,  GLOBAL_CARS_CROSSING %d\n"), GetCurrentThreadId(), paramsPtr->direction, paramsPtr->numTraversingCar, globalCarsCrossing);
        if (paramsPtr->numTraversingCar == 0) {
            _tprintf(_T("RELEASED\n"));
            ReleaseSemaphore(paramsPtr->bridgeSem, 1, NULL);
        }
    ReleaseMutex(paramsPtr->mutex);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: great explanation! Thank you so much!

Comment: Just one more question if you have time. I was reading the official documentation and I found this: If a thread calls LeaveCriticalSection when it does not have ownership of the specified critical section object, an error occurs that may cause another thread using EnterCriticalSection to wait indefinitely. So is it correct to use a critical section to block the tunnel in this case? Because the thread that enters in the critical section could not be the same that leaves it.

Comment: @Jacob Indeed, you're right... I was just lucky it work on my computer... Instead I sshould have used semaphore (editing....)